# Ruby 1.8.6 app cannot start (cannot remove Object::Helpers (NameError))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

after a Windows Update automatic server restart our Ruby dev app won't start anymore. No new changes in the repository. I have no clue where to go from here. Anyone?

```
C:\webapp>ruby script/server -p3002
=> Booting Mongrel (use 'script/server webrick' to force WEBrick)
=> Rails application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3002
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3002
** Starting Rails with development environment...
GLoc v1.2 running in development mode. Strings can be modified at runtime.
Exiting
./script/../config/../vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in `remove_const': cannot remove Object::Helpers (NameError)
        from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in `send'
        from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in `remove_constant'
        from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:368:in `new_constants_in'
        from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:368:in `each'
        from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:368:in `new_constants_in'
        from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `require'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in `rails'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in `cloaker_'
         ... 19 levels...
        from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:39
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'

        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from script/server:3

C:\webapp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something happened to the ODBC data source somehow. Our ODBC data source had been 64-bit for weeks, but for the app to work again, I had to create a 32-bit data source using `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.